# React - implement a component as js api

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a stack of toast messages in my app.
I dont want to re-draw the `<Toast` component over and over again.
My need is to call it as a function and it will render itself
Something like:

```
Toast.push({time: 5, message: 'Data was submitted', type: 'success'});
Toast.push({time: 2, message: 'Data was not processed yet', type: 'warn'});
```

This way I can manage the DOM array inside the component and it will be some sort of a singleton component.  **One instance for the entire app**
Is it possible to call and display a component like: `Toast.push(...);`
Im using function based components with the latest react

**Update**
This concept is implemented in ant.design https://ant.design/components/message/ - `message.warn('Some message')`.
I want to avoid props and contexts... It needs to be as simple as possible... `Toast.push(...)` that's it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `useToast` hook, returning an element and a `push` function.

```js
//App.js
import useToast from "./useToast";
export default function App() {
  const { toast, push } = useToast();
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Your stuff here</p>
      {toast}
      <button onClick={() => push({ message: "hi" })} />
    </div>
  );
}

//useToast.js
import { useState } from "react";
export default function useToast(initial = []) {
  const [list, setList] = useState(initial);
  return {
    push(data) {
      setList([...list, data]);
    },
    toast: (
      <ul>
        {list.map(({ message }, i) => <li key={i}>{message}</li>)}
      </ul>
    ),
  };
}
```

Comment: I know how to implement that, see my update. I have clarified more. Thanks

Comment: I will update my answer

Comment: Check it now. I'm not sure if this will work for you but I hope it does

Comment: It works, but `useToast` is not a singletoe, I wan to call the `push` method from the entire app, and only one instance of it will be live. When ever I do `{toast}`, I will render another instance, I want to avoid that. thanks again